# Python Script to copy define line in C files

Tags: python, c, header

I am having some trouble with a script. My task is to read in a bunch of .h (files written in c) files and I am capable of doing that using:

myfiles glob.glob('*.h')

but the struggle I am having is once these files are being read in, I need to take the `#define` line and paste it below that and change it. Confusing I know but an example would be:

```
#ifndefine _THIS_CODE_NEEDS_COPIED_H
#define _THIS_CODE_NEEDS_COPIED_H

#define THIS_CODE_NEEDS_COPIED_VERSION "10" <----thats what I need to add! 
                                        Noting: it loses one underscore 
                                    after define and the H is changed to
                                   VERSION with a String "10" at the end.
```

Yes, it seems as though it would be simple but I am not sure how to read python in character by character. Any suggestions?! Minding, this is a new line copied and then edited below those others. Also, this is many files. There are hundreds of this! And all of their #define's read something different after them (ex: another might be #define _THIS_IS_DIFFERENT_H). So they would not all say the same thing. Please, help! My brain can't take anymore!

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question you posted yesterday? Why not edit rather than post it again?

Comment: Please post your Python code.

Comment: I got my code working but if your interested I have another question posted, a little more complex I have been struggling with for days. It involves that same line, and comparing.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke btw your profile says you wanna make a space craft, well that's funny because although my Python is minimal, I actually am a software engineer for people who make aircrafts (and space)

Comment: @Meg.Pazzaglia oh cool, which company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) modules:

```
import fileinput
import glob
import re
import sys

files = glob.glob('*.h')
pattern = re.compile(r'#define\s+_([_A-Z]+)_H\s+$')
realstdout = sys.stdout

for line in fileinput.input(files, inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    m = pattern.match(line)
    if m:
        sys.stdout.write('\n#define %s_VERSION "10"\n' % m.group(1))
        realstdout.write('%s: %s\n'%(fileinput.filename(),m.group(1)))
```

Notes:

- The call to [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) iterates over files in the list that is passed in as the first argument.
- The `inplace` parameter to `fileinput.input()` indicates that you are editing the files *in place*. That is, they files will be replaced by whatever your program writes to standard output.
- The regular expression [matches](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) the sort of `#define` that you say you are looking for. Additionally, the parentheses `()` in it capture a substring of that match.
- Inside the loop, we maintain the existing content by writing every single line of every file. Additionally, if we see the magic `#define`, then we write one extra line.
- The business with `realstdout` provides a log of which files were modified, and what patterns were detected.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! My REGEX is a little shaky so no wonder I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Please *upvote* each answer that you found useful by clicking on the up-arrow near the answer. If one answer fully answers your question, please *accept* it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Thanks Rob! Any suggestions where to go for Python Help?

Comment: For specific questions, ask on Stack Overflow. To gain general knowledge, try to answer some questions on Stack Overflow. To learn about Python from scratch, try [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: Any suggestions on how to use filecmp to scan a line in a directory? I know how to do it with one file to another but what about an entire directory?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read in character-by-character to do this in Python. This could be done in fewer lines of code but it would be even uglier and harder to follow than it is now:

```
with open("input_file.txt", "rb") as f:  # you can use glob or os.walk as needed to get input files
    with open("output_file.txt", "w") as out:  # output file, adjust as needed
        for line in f:  # iterate through each line
            new_line = line  # make new_line to be written equal to current line
            if line.startswith("#define"):
                tokens = line.strip().split(' ')
                sp = 1 if tokens[-1].startswith('_') else 0  # skip initial underscore if present by adjusting start position (sp)
                def_list = tokens[-1][sp:].split('_')
                if def_list[-1] == 'H':
                    def_list[-1] = 'VERSION'
                    new_line = '_'.join(def_list) + ' "10"'
            out.write("%s\n" % new_line)  # write new_line to file
```

This will change lines as needed and write unaffected lines to the new file as is. If it is required to have an underscore prefix to the ones needing to be changed that can be modified also, currently this script handles it either way by adjusting the start position (`sp`).